# If else inside SQL Where clause throws error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My Stored Procedure is like this

```
    alter  PROCEDURE ph_GetAllStaffAddressByCamp
    @CampCode  VARCHAR(20)

AS

IF NULLIF(@CampCode, '') IS NULL

    DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(2)
    EXEC cs_GetCurrentYear @Year OUTPUT

    SELECT DISTINCT [VolID], [CampID]  FROM [vStaffJobAndCamp]
 WHERE 
IF @CampCode IS NULL
    CampCode like @Year +%
ELSE
    CampCode = @CampCode
```

Everything looks okay to me, But it throws compile error like this

```
    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ph_GetAllStaffAddressByCamp, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ph_GetAllStaffAddressByCamp, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'CampCode'.
```

Does any one know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot BEGIN...END in IF clause. And WHERE conditions was also wrong

```
    alter  PROCEDURE ph_GetAllStaffAddressByCamp
    @CampCode  VARCHAR(20)

AS

IF NULLIF(@CampCode, '') IS NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(2)
    EXEC cs_GetCurrentYear @Year OUTPUT

    SELECT DISTINCT [VolID], [CampID]  FROM [vStaffJobAndCamp]
 WHERE 
(@CampCode IS NULL and CampCode like @Year +%) OR
(@CampCode IS NOT NULL and CampCode = @CampCode)
END
```

Comment: It cann't be correct, because it returns nothing if @CampCode <> ''

Comment: @WadimX Start topic question was about the syntax error, not about logic of a query.

Comment: And You changed logic by adding BEGIN...END ;)

Answer (score 1):

`IF` is not a valid SQL keyword. Therefore, you cannot use it inside a `SELECT` statement.

You could express those conditions in valid SQL like so:

```sql
WHERE 
  (@CampCode IS NULL AND CampCode like @Year + '%')
  OR
  (@CampCode is NOT NULL AND CampCode = @CampCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

case Campcode
 WHEN @CampCode IS NULL
  THEN CampCode like @Year +%
ELSE CampCode = @CampCode
END

use case instead of IF condition in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good execution plan, you should avoid OR logic in WHERE clauses.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ph_GetAllStaffAddressByCamp
    @CampCode  VARCHAR(20)
AS
IF @CampCode IS NULL OR @CampCode = ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(2)
    EXEC cs_GetCurrentYear @Year OUTPUT
    SELECT DISTINCT [VolID], [CampID]  FROM [vStaffJobAndCamp]
    WHERE CampCode LIKE @Year+'%'
END
ELSE
    SELECT DISTINCT [VolID], [CampID]  FROM [vStaffJobAndCamp]
    WHERE CampCode = @CampCode
```